# Flutter & riverpod: How to use ".when" with a provider

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I'm trying to use ".when" method on a provider I created but I got "The method when isn't defined for the type Future"

I would like to use a service class for all my bluetooth method.

```
part 'bluetooth_manager.g.dart';

@riverpod
class BluetoothService extends _$BluetoothService {
  @override
  void build() {}

  Future<List<Device>> discoverDevices() async {
    //Scan devices
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5));
  }
}
```

View:

```
class ModulesView extends ConsumerWidget {
  const ModulesView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {

    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
        child: ref.watch(bluetoothServiceProvider.notifier).discoverDevices().when(
              data: (data) => modulesFound(ref, data),
              loading: () => loading(),
              error: (error, stacktrace) => ErrorView(errorMessage: "errorMessage", retryFunction: () {}),
            ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `discoverDevices` is just a regular function. You should expose the value from the provider itself, by making it the returned value of the `build` method. That way, you can call `ref.watch(bluetoothServiceProvider).when(...)`.

Comment: Ok but what if I have discoverDevices, connectDevice, disconnectDevice etc...? Should I stop using a "service class" and just expose all my method with @riverpod annotation?

Comment: Functions like `disconnectDevice` are more likely to be called imperatively, so it can stay as a method in the notifier. You can still call it like `ref.read(discoverDevicesProvider.notifier).disconnectDevice();`. What you need to expose is just the value that you want to watch

Comment: Can you give me a simple example please? I'd just like to have a BluetoothService class with all my future methods, and for "discoverDevices", after 5s, change the UI of my view with the "when" method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a value to update the UI, you can simply declare

```
@riverpod
Future<List<Device>> deviceList(DeviceListRef ref) async {
  // the content of your discoverDevices method
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5));
  return listOfDevices;
}
```

then you should be able to watch in the builder

```
class ModulesView extends ConsumerWidget {
  const ModulesView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final discorverDevice = ref.watch(deviceListProvider);

    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
        child: discorverDevice.when(
              data: (data) => modulesFound(ref, data),
              loading: () => loading(),
              error: (error, stacktrace) => ErrorView(errorMessage: "errorMessage", retryFunction: () {}),
            ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

otherwise you can call a doSomething() from BluetoothService for exemple with ref.read inside a method

```
ref.read(bluetoothServiceProvider.notifier).doSomething();
```

or you can use solution of Dhafin Rayhan depends on your need

Comment: Thanks for your help @FaBotch, you and Dhafin, I finally understand how to use Riverpod 2.0 correctly!

Comment: 1) Calling `ref.read` inside the body of another provider is discouraged, as now `discorverDeviceProvider` won't be reactive to the changes of `bluetoothServiceProvider`. This could lead into bugs and hard time debugging. See [this](https://riverpod.dev/docs/essentials/combining_requests#the-refread-method). 2) This line `ref.read(bluetoothServiceProvider).doSomething();` is wrong. You can't call a method of the notifier if you only read the provider. 3) The examples here make big changes from what given by @Naografix in the post, in which code-generated providers are used.

Comment: I have updated my answer considering https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/about_code_generation

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `discoverDevices` is just a regular function. If you need to expose its value so that you can "watch" it, make it the returned value of the `build` method. Other methods that don't need their values to be watched can stay in the notifier. You can call them and get their values imperatively, for example in a button callback.

```dart
@riverpod
class DiscoveredDevices extends _$DiscoveredDevices {
  @override
  Future<List<Device>> build() {
    // ...
    return aListOfDevices;
  }

  Future<void> disconnectDevice(id) async {
    // ...
  }

  // An example of how you can still have a method that returns some value.
  // In this scenario, you may call this method imperatively and wait for
  // its future to complete, and then use the value maybe to show a snackbar
  // or something
  Future<bool> connectDevice(id) async {
    // ...
    return true;
  }
}
```

In your widget, you can use it like this (I use explicit type annotations for clarity):

```dart
class ExampleScreen extends ConsumerWidget {
  const ExampleScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final AsyncValue<List<Device>> discoveredDevices = ref.watch(discoveredDevicesProvider);

    return Scaffold(
      body: discoveredDevices.when(
        loading: () => const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
        error: (_, __) => const Center(child: Text('An error occured')),
        data: (List<Device> data) => ListView.builder(
          // ...
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          // This value is not being watched, you can call it like this just to get
          // the value every time the button is pressed
          final isSuccess = await ref.read(discoveredDevicesProvider.notifier).connectDevice(id);
          // ...
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Generally, it should follow the pattern from [this example](https://riverpod.dev/docs/essentials/side_effects#exposing-a-method-to-perform-a-post-request).

Comment: Thanks for your help @Dhafin, you and FaBotch, I finally understand how to use Riverpod 2.0 correctly!